# Magento2 : Overriding Model file not working

Tags: magento2, module, override-model

I want to override `Magento\Payment\Model\Info::setAdditionalInformation()` function my code is as below

```
<preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Info" type="Xxx\Yyy\Model\Payment\Info" />
```

and file is `app\code\Xxx\Yyy\Model\Payment\Info.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Xxx\Yyy\Model\Payment;

/**
 * Payment information model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Info extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Info
{
    /**
     * Additional information container
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_additionalInformation = [];

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $extensionFactory,
        $customAttributeFactory,
        $paymentData,
        $encryptor,
        $resource,
        $$resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
}

public function setAdditionalInformation($key, $value = null)
{
    if (is_object($value)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The payment disallows storing object XXXXXXXXXXXX'));
    }

    $this->_initAdditionalInformation();
    if (is_array($key) && $value === null) {
        $this->_additionalInformation = $key;
    } else {
        $this->_additionalInformation[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $this->setData('additional_information', $this->_additionalInformation);
}
```

}

When I compiled not getting any error,but unfortunately I cant override this function.
**EDIT**
my di.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Advanced" type="Tecksky\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Advanced" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare" type="Xxx\Yyy\Helper\Product\Compare" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts" type="Xxx\Yyy\CustomerData\CompareProducts" />
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" type="Xxx\Yyy\Block\Account\Customer" />

    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Index" type="Xxx\Yyy\Controller\CatalogSearch" />
    <preference for="Magento\Search\Controller\Term\Popular" type="Xxx\Yyy\Controller\Searchterm" />
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Guest\Form" type="Xxx\Yyy\Controller\Guestform" />
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Info" type="Xxx\Yyy\Model\Payment\Info" />

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
        <plugin name="addBodyclass" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Result\Page"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="ts_checkout_layout_processor" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper">
        <plugin name="checkout_cart_total_ajax_error" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper" sortOrder="100" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you share complete di.xml please?

Comment: i have added code @LAW

Comment: You shouldn’t take ownership of the class just to modify one function. Instead, you should do an “after” plugin.

Comment: Yes I agree with @ShawnAbramson If it is for one method you use plugin method.

Comment: can you answer it? i want to remove 'if (is_object($value)) {' condition which throe exception

Comment: You can do an around plugin to remove that. However, if you don’t call the parent, any other around or after plugins on that method won’t fire.

Comment: I’m saying this to be helpful, not condescending, but based on the contents of your di.xml file, you would greatly benefit from reading through the Magento docs and also following some Alan Storm tutorials. Mainly bc with all of those overrides, you’re going to have a difficult time upgrading your platform when 2.3 or higher rolls out.

Comment: @KetanBorada This is a helpful tutorial for you to get started - 
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-override-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-using-plugin-preference/

Refer to module Override using plugin.

Comment: I can answer tomorrow. I’m typing from the comfort of my bed right now.

Comment: ok sure @ShawnAbramson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modules di.xml file you will have to declare the tag preference
to override a file:

```
<preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Info" type="Xxx\Yyy\Model\Payment\Info" />
```

You can override the file depending on the area or for both areas i.e adminhtml and frontend.

Comment: can you explain where i made mistake in di.xml file check in my question

Comment: Can you tell me the location where your di.xml file is stored? I mean the full path to the di.xml.

Comment: app\code\Xxx\Yyy\etc\di.xml other overriding is working just this not working

Comment: Is your module installed in the magento instance ?

Comment: yes it is,extension working fine i have just add this override rule

Comment: Did you try putting a die in the method and check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81440/discussion-between-ketan-borada-and-sourabh-kumar-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

please try replacing your constructor with below code:

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
array $data = []
) {
parent::__construct(
    $context,
    $registry,
    $extensionFactory,
    $customAttributeFactory,
    $paymentData,
    $encryptor
);
```

}

IF it not work please let me know which error are you facing?

Comment: Can you please that before replacing construct code  which error are you facing?

Comment: Sorry, not getting any error just overriding not works